# Conditional image style in Views

Tags: views, media

How can I apply different image style to an image field in Views, based on the condition of some other field of the same content type? I need to print the image with some frame, if some field (checkbox) is true, and with other style if the field is false. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I have not tried it myself but might Views Conditional do the trick? https://www.drupal.org/project/views_conditional

Answer (score 4):

Add the image field twice(!) to the fields list. Use the frame style on the first image and the no-frame style on the second. Exclude both fields from display and place them before the checkbox.

Next, rewrite the output of the checkbox field to use [field_image] if the checkbox is checked (normal rewrite) and [field_image_1] if it is not (no result behaviour, Treat 0 as empty).